# Function receiving sort with 2 parameters in the constructor

Tags: z3, theorem-proving

I have created 4 sorts (Task,Role,User and Run) the last one receives 2 parameters, then I declare a fun for each of them, including one for Run , call P which receives 2 parameters to create an "instance" of Run. Then I have created two arrays one containing  a User-Role "relation" (Privs)and the other one containing a Role-Task "Relation" (Roles). I use this two arrays to assert if  when looking a user u, it has a role r in Privs and if when looking a role r in Roles it has a task t.  Until now I manage to do this in separate lines like this:

```
(declare-sort Task)
(declare-sort Role)
(declare-sort User)
(declare-sort Run 2)
(define-sort P (User Role) (Run User Role))
(declare-fun t () Task)
(declare-fun r () Role)
(declare-fun u () User)
(declare-const Privs (Array User Role))
(declare-const Roles (Array Role Task))


(assert (= (select Privs u) r))
(assert (= (select Roles r) t))
```

But now I am trying to make a fun which receives a Run (User,Role pair) and inside the function assert the same but for all users in P and all its roles. Can this be done by passing a Run sort variable to the function??.. for accessing its elements (User, Role) inside??

Answer (score 0):

Your use of parametric types seems overkill: you only use "Run" with sorts instantiated to "User" and "Role". So why should you have to make "Run" parametric.
The definition for parametric sorts and use cases is described in detail at http://smtlib.org, Z3 implements this common format so there is nothing particular to Z3 about your question.